# DB2 Triggers execution order

Tags: triggers, db2, execution

Given....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NotaRandomUpdate (@table1_id INT, @new_value INT)
AS
BEGIN
    begin transaction
        UPDATE  Table1
        SET     field1 = @new_value
        WHERE   id = @table1_id

        INSERT INTO Table2 VALUE(@new_value)
    end transaction
END
```

In the above (very) simplified situation, if there are 2 seperate TRIGGERS, one on each of Table1 & Table2, which trigger would execute 1st?

I'm looking to take the combined result of the full transaction (with information not referenced in the transaction itself) and save that combined result eleswhere - so I need to bring data from the join of Table1=>Table2 out.

If Table1-Trigger executes 1st, then I'm faced with not having data needed (at that instance) from Table2.
If Table2-Trigger executes 1st, then I'm faced with not having data needed (at that instance) from Table1.

I presume the triggers only execute during/after the commit phase....or are they executed immediately the Table1-update & Table-insert statements are executed and thus the overall database updates are wrapped up inside the full transaction?

This is due to happen in a DB2 database.

Is a solution possible?.
Or am I faced with running a "some time later" activity (like pre-EOD) which executes a query which joins the 2 tables after all relevent updates (for that day) have been completed, providing of course that each of Table1 & Table2 have some timestamp columns that can be tracked.

end

Comment: Not enough details. Specify the *trigger event* details (before/after insert/update) for both tables because that partially determines execution order. When two or more triggers of the same type and triggering-event exist on same table the execution order is the trigger-creation order. Your sproc syntax is invalid for Db2-LUW, do you mean an explicit commit where you write 'end transaction'?   Depending on exactly what the triggers do, the access-plan can also help view the sequence.

Comment: Trigger code is compiled into the DML statement that triggers it and is executed as a single section.

Comment: Any relevant triggers for Table1 will fire before any relevant triggers on Table 2 , assuming no rollback.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Please ignore the syntax errors.  The DB2 manual talks of trigger execution ordering being determined by the trigger type and trigger creation order when both triggers are on the same table.  In this instance each table has 1 trigger.  Your last comment (mao) appears relevent, but do you have a reference to back it up?

Answer (score 1):

Any relevant triggers for Table1 will fire before any relevant triggers on Table2 , assuming no rollback.

Db2 [triggers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html) execute with Insert or Update or Delete statements, whether per-row or per-statement. Hence the statements inside trigger body will only run (assuming trigger is valid) during execution of the triggering statement. Commit will not invoke trigger logic.

Each of your Insert/Update/Delete statements that executes will execute any relevant valid triggers during execution of that statement before execution of the next statement will begin.